# Partial derivative composition graphically

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, graphing-functions

In the following expression

$$
\int_{y_2}^{y_1}\cfrac{\partial P}{\partial y}dy = P(x, y)|^{y_1}_{y_2}
$$

I understand algebraically the transition (it is the composite rule and Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for $yy$ direction of the multivariable $P$ function). But what does it mean geometrically? I feel like it is right from a manipulation standpoint but can't quite grasp the geometric meaning of to what it is referring to in a graph. Is it just the projection of the function in the $zOy$ plane?

Answer (score 1):

For an arbitrary but fixed $x$ define the function $f_x$ by $f_x(y) = P(x,y)$. Then, by definition,
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y} f_x(y)
= \frac{\partial}{\partial y} P(x,y)
$$
and so your statement is equivalent to the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus applied to $f_x$:
$$
\int_{y_1}^{y_2} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y} f_x(y) 
= f_x(y) \bigg|_{y_1}^{y_2}, 
$$
which can be interpreted as a geometric statement about net change of $f_x$ or area under the curve of $(f_x)'$ in the plane at fixed $x$-coordinate parallel to the $yz$-plane, **as you suggest.**